# Is there a way to print image displayed on a tkinter label?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

I created a `tkinter` displaying image exported from `sqlite` file, can I write a function to print that image(A3 or A4)? that's a sample of my code:

```py
def Display():
    global img
    notebook.select(self.Tab_Control2)
    conn = sqlite3.connect('datastorage.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    filename = "SELECT * from Structure1"
    c.execute(filename)
    record = c.fetchall()
    for row in record:
        print(row)
        photo=row[0]
        fp = io.BytesIO(photo)
        image = Image.open(fp)
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        panel = Label(self.Tab_Control2, image=img)
        panel.image = img
        panel.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Do you know why you have the `panel.image = img` line? If you think about it, it's the same reason that's causing your problem right now. `panel` is going out of scope so the image is deleted from memory. Put all of the labels in a list and make that list global.

Comment: What do you mean by "print that image(A3 or A4)"? Image resizing?

Comment: yes I mean that

Comment: I see you are using the Pillow library. Pay attention to [`image.resize()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize).